# h2 mixed mode connection problem

Tags: h2

I start h2 database in a servlet context listener:

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
     org.h2.Driver.load();
     String apprealPath = sce.getServletContext().getRealPath("\\");
     String h2Url = "jdbc:h2:file:" + apprealPath + "DB\\cdb;AUTO_SERVER=true";
     LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(); 
        StatusPrinter.print(lc); 
     logger.debug("h2 url : " + h2Url);
     try {
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection(h2Url, "sa", "sa");
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  logger.debug("h2 database started in embedded mode");
        sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("connection", conn);
    }
```

then I try to use dbvisualizer to connect to h2 using following url :

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/cdb
```

but get these error messages:

```
An error occurred while establishing the connection:
   Type: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException   Error Code: 90067   SQL State: 90067
Message:
   Connection is broken: "Connection refused: connect" [90067-148]
```

I tried to replace localhost with "172.17.33.181:58524" (I found it in cdb.lock.db)
reconnect with user "sa" password "sa" ,then server response changed to :
wrong username or password !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the [Automatic Mixed Mode](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#auto_mixed_mode), you don't need to (and you can't) use `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost`. Just use the same URL everywhere, that means `jdbc:h2:file:...DB\\cdb;AUTO_SERVER=true`.

You can use the same database URL independent of whether the database is already open or not. Explicit client/server connections (using jdbc:h2:tcp:// or ssl://) are not supported.

Comment: hi, Thomas I want help to translate H2 documentation into Simplied-Chinese.

Comment: I believe there is already an effort to translate the documentation, see http://groups.google.com/group/h2-cn

Comment: China people can not access google group except they use network proxy software.Our Government Firewall is damned.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Is access to the h2database.com web site possible from within China?

Comment: This just saved my day. Was manually starting servers and struggling to find a sane way of starting the h2 server after my environment loads but before database connections occurred (frameworks ftw...).

Comment: @ThomasMueller - I am facing a similar problem. I want to start a h2 database server and have multiple local applications connect to it. Should I be starting the server in mixed mode? If so, how should the code to start the server look like? Given that I would need only the tcp server, I thought of using Server.createTcpServer() method but this doesn't accept a url. Please share your insights. Thanks!