# Exception while trying to connect to H2 database setup for Activiti

Tags: java, tomcat, h2, activiti

I am trying to setup standalone H2 DB to tryout some basic Activiti stuff.
But whenever I try to start tomcat I get an exception:

```
    09:32:57,270 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl  - Exception while initializing Database connection
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Wrong user name or password [28000-191]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.validateUserAndPassword(Engine.java:333)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:161)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:136)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:149)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:606)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.initTransfer(SessionRemote.java:129)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:430)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:311)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:107)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:91)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:74)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(SimpleDriverDataSource.java:140)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:120)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:225)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.getMetaData(Unknown Source)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.initDatabaseType(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.java:836)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.initDataSource(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.java:786)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.init(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.java:602)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.buildProcessEngine(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.java:590)
    at org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration.buildProcessEngine(SpringProcessEngineConfiguration.java:65)
    at org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean.getObject(ProcessEngineFactoryBean.java:60)
    at org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean.getObject(ProcessEngineFactoryBean.java:32)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor$1.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:379)
    at org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fe4dada2.getObject(<generated>)
    at org.activiti.explorer.conf.ActivitiEngineConfiguration.processEngine(ActivitiEngineConfiguration.java:83)
    at org.activiti.explorer.conf.ActivitiEngineConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4bdf3172.CGLIB$processEngine$3(<generated>)
    at org.activiti.explorer.conf.ActivitiEngineConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4bdf3172$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a52c8ed.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at org.activiti.explorer.conf.ActivitiEngineConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4bdf3172.processEngine(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:322)
    at org.activiti.explorer.conf.ActivitiEngineConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4bdf3172.processEngine(<generated>)
    at org.activiti.explorer.conf.ActivitiEngineConfiguration.identityService(ActivitiEngineConfiguration.java:159)
    at org.activiti.explorer.conf.ActivitiEngineConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4bdf3172.CGLIB$identityService$10(<generated>)
    at org.activiti.explorer.conf.ActivitiEngineConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4bdf3172$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a52c8ed.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at org.activiti.explorer.conf.ActivitiEngineConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4bdf3172.identityService(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.activiti.explorer.servlet.WebConfigurer.contextInitialized(WebConfigurer.java:40)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:945)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1795)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My tomcat/webapps/WEB_INF/classes/db.properties is:

```
db=h2
jdbc.driver=org.h2.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test
jdbc.username=sa
jdbc.password=
```

And my activiti.cfg.xml is:

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration">

    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test" />
   <!-- <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:h2:mem:activiti;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=1000" /> -->
    <property name="jdbcDriver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUsername" value="sa" />
    <property name="jdbcPassword" value="" />
    <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true" />

    <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="false" />
    <property name="asyncExecutorEnabled" value="true" />
    <property name="asyncExecutorActivate" value="false" />

    <property name="mailServerHost" value="mail.my-corp.com" />
    <property name="mailServerPort" value="5025" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

My project hierarchy is:

[image]

and I am able to log into H2 console using credentials sa/sa:

[image]

**EDIT#1**

I am not sure how to set username/password. I am using the default settings only.

I managed to log into H2 console using credentials sa/sa.

in my tomcat/webapps..../db.properties and activiti.cfg.xml I have:

```
jdbc.username=sa
jdbc.password=
```

&

```
<property name="jdbcUsername" value="sa" />
<property name="jdbcPassword" value="" />
```

respectively.

I had also tried by setting password value as "sa" in these two files. But in that case I get a different error:

```
01:36:27,467 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl  - Exception while closing the Database connection
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Connection is broken: "unexpected status 16777216" [90067-176]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:344)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:178)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:154)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:621)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.close(SessionRemote.java:552)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.close(JdbcConnection.java:383)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doCloseConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:341)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doReleaseConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:328)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.close(Unknown Source)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.initDatabaseType(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.java:850)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.initDataSource(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.java:786)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.init(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.java:602)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.buildProcessEngine(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.java:590)
    at org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration.buildProcessEngine(SpringProcessEngineConfiguration.java:65)
    at org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean.getObject(ProcessEngineFactoryBean.java:60)
    at org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean.getObject(ProcessEngineFactoryBean.java:32)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor$1.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:379)
    at org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8028cc4c.getObject(<generated>)
    at org.activiti.explorer.conf.ActivitiEngineConfiguration.processEngine(ActivitiEngineConfiguration.java:83)
    at org.activiti.explorer.conf.ActivitiEngineConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fa2b185e.CGLIB$processEngine$3(<generated>)
    at org.activiti.explorer.conf.ActivitiEngineConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fa2b185e$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c9dbd5a6.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at org.activiti.explorer.conf.ActivitiEngineConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fa2b185e.processEngine(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
```

**EDIT#2**

Ok, I just replaced the JdbcUrl in activiti.cfg.xml from `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test` to `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/activiti`
and tomcat is now starting fine, without errors. Not sure what happened.
I now log into H2 console without password just sa/"", works

I can now execute my BookOrderTest(the test case that uses H2 standalone DB) successfully BUT I still can't see a new queued task being created due to this test run at `localhost/activiti-explorer` web-app.
Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Downvoters please take some time to provide the reason of downvote.

Answer (score 3):

We just faced the similar issue. The problem is that Activiti already comes with a h2*.jar or some version. And in our case server and client versions didn't match - it caused constant exceptions upon start

- Deleve h2*.jar file from Activiti's lib folder.
- Copy h2*.jar from your H2 server setup into lib.
- Restart Tomcat (or whatever you have)

Answer (score 0):

From your activit.cfg.xml

`<property name="jdbcPassword" value="" />`

From your db.properties

`jdbc.password=`

You said that you were able to connect using sa/sa but have empty password values in your files, it must be "sa"

**EDIT #1**

First of all, set your password "sa" in both activiti.cfg.xml and db.properties files.

Because you are trying basic stuff, it could be better to start with an in memory database: [h2 in-memory database](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases)

Just set:

- in your db.properties:

          `jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:`
- in your activiti.cfg.xml:

          `<property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:h2:mem:"/>`

If you want to run H2 under mixed mode read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525586/h2-mixed-mode-connection-problem), that points to [mixed mode](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#auto_mixed_mode), I think that's what you're trying to achieve.

Mixed mode configuration:

- in your db.properties:

          `jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:/data/test;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE`
- in your activiti.cfg.xml:

          `<property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:h2:/data/test;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE"/>`

Comment: I had tried using sa as password in those file. Please see EDIT#1 for details.

Comment: Well, my code works fine when I use in-memory database. I am only having issues with standalone DB. Also, I had some advancements with standalone settings. See Edit#3 for details.

Comment: in your activiti-explorer project, under activiti-explorer\WEB-INF\classes you'll find the same `db.properties` and  `activiti.cfg.xml` files. Point the jdbc url to your database

Comment: Under activiti-explorer\WEB-INF\classes I only have db.properties file, updating which to have jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/activiti causing Connection is broken: "unexpected status 16777216" [90067-176] while starting tomcat.

Comment: So now that you're trying to run activti in an standalone DB, check [this activiti's forum link](https://forums.activiti.org/content/h2-standalone-database-difficulties).